# How to define a catch-all enum value when casting from an integer?

Tags: c#, enums

I've got a enum type defined in my C# code that corresponds to all possible values for the NetConnectionStatus field in Win32_NetworkAdapter WMI table, as [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394216(v=vs.85).aspx).

The documentation shows that the integers 0 through 12 each have a unique status name, but then all integers between 13 and 65,535 are lumped into one bucket called "Other." So here's my code:

```
[Serializable]
public enum NetConnectionStatus
{
    Disconnected = 0,
    Connecting = 1,
    Connected = 2,
    Disconnecting = 3,
    HardwareNotPresent = 4,
    HardwareDisabled = 5,
    HardwareMalfunction = 6,
    MediaDisconnected = 7,
    Authenticating = 8,
    AuthenticationSucceeded = 9,
    AuthenticationFailed = 10,
    InvalidAddress = 11,
    CredentialsRequired = 12,
    Other
}
```

This works fine for the values that are *not* Other. For instance, I can do this:

```
var result = (NetConnectionStatus) 2;
Assert.AreEqual(NetConnectionStatus.Connected, result);
```

But for anything in that higher numeric range, it doesn't work so great. I would like it if I could do this:

```
var result = (NetConnectionStatus) 20;
Assert.AreEqual(NetConnectionStatus.Other, result);
```

But right now that `result` variable gets assigned the literal value `20` instead of `Other`. Is there some out-of-the-box way of accomplishing this, something akin to `Parse()` but for integers instead of strings, or perhaps some special attribute I'm unaware of? I would prefer to not write my own wrapper method for this if there is already a good way to accomplish this.

Comment: nope .net doesn't have that. you should write something yourself.

Comment: Just because no one has said it yet `(int)NetConnectionStatus.Other == 13`

Answer (score 2):

If you have a string value, then the closest thing I can think of is to use `Enum.TryParse`:

```
NetConnectionStatus result;

if (Enum.TryParse(stringValue, out result) == false)
    result = NetConnectionStatus.Other;
```

For an integer value that you're casting, you can use:

```
result = (NetConnectionStatus)integerValue;
if (Enum.GetValues(typeof(NetConnectionStatus)).Contains(result) == false)
    result = NetConnectionStatus.Other;
```

Not really ideal, but in C# enums aren't much more than fancy names for integral values, so it's valid to stuff an integer value not in the defined values of the enums into a value of that enum type.

This solution will handle negative numbers, or cases where you have gaps in your enum values more elegantly than doing numerical comparisons.

Comment: I think this is almost correct. While it's more clunky than a `>12` or a `>Other` check, it carries the intent of assigning all other values to `Other`, doesn't change if items are added to the enum and doesn't rely on `Other` being last. The one change I would make is using `if(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyEnum), value)`

Answer (score 0):

it would be nice but no. How about

```
var result = (NetConnectionStatus) 20;
Assert.IsTrue(result >= (int)NetConnectionStatus.Other);
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET does not such thing as a "any other" enumeration value bucket. Technically, enumeration (enum) is a pretty set of named constants of some *underlying* type (which is one of following: `sbyte`, `short`, `int`, `long` and their unsigned counterparts). You can cast an enum value to/from a corresponding type without any losses, as in this example:

```
enum TestEnum:int // Explicitly stating a type.
{
    OnlyElement=0
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Console.WriteLine implicitly calls ToString of the TestEnum.OnlyElement.
        Console.WriteLine("OnlyElement == {0}", TestEnum.OnlyElement);

        //TestEnum.OnlyElement equals to 0, as demonstrated by this casting:
        Console.WriteLine("(int)OnlyElement == {0}", (int)TestEnum.OnlyElement);

        //We can do it in reverse...
        Console.WriteLine("(TestEnum)0 == ",(TestEnum)0); 

        // But what happens when we try to cast a value, which is not
        // representable by any of enum's named constants,
        // into value of enum in question? No exception is thrown 
        // whatsoever: enum variable simply holds that value, and, 
        // having no named constant to associate it with, simply returns
        // that value when attempting to "ToString"ify it:
        Console.WriteLine("(TestEnum)5 == {0}", (TestEnum)5); //prints "(TestEnum)5 == 5".

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I'd like to repeat it again, enum in .NET is simply a *value of the underlying type* with some nice decorations like overriden ToString method and flags checking (look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/enum-flags) if you want to know more about flags). You cannot have an integer with only 14 values like "0..12 and *everything else*", and so you cannot have such enum. In your example, `NetConnectionStatus.Other` simply receives single literal value (I assume it would most probably be '13', as the next available positive value of underlying type - however it actually depends on the compiler) as any other enumeration constant would do if not specified explicitly - and, obviously, it does not become a bucket.

However, there are options to achieve simple equation checks for integers/bytes/shorts/longs - and enums alike. Consider this extension method:

```
static bool IsOther(this NetConnectionStatus A)
{
    return (A < (NetConnectionStatus)0) || (A > (NetConnectionStatus)12);
}
```

Now you can have a simple assertion like this:

```
var result = (NetConnectionStatus)10;
Trace.Assert(result.IsOther()); //No assertion is triggered; result is NetConnectionStatus.AuthenticationFailed
```

and

```
var result = (NetConnectionStatus)20;
Trace.Assert(result.IsOther()); //Assertion failed; result is undefined!
```

(Of course you can replace `IsOther` method with `IsNotOther`, overload it and pretty much anything else you could do with a method.)

Now there is one more thing. `Enum` class itself contains a method called `IsDefined`, which allows you to avoid checks for specific enum's value boundaries (`<0`, `>12`), therefore preventing unwanted bugs in case enum values would ever be added/removed, at the small performance cost of unboxing and checking each value in enum for a match (I'm not sure how this works under the hood though, I hope these checks are optimized). So your method would look like this:

```
    static bool IsOther(NetConnectionStatus A)
    {
        return !Enum.IsDefined(typeof(NetConnectionStatus), A);
    }
```

(However, concluding from enum's name, it seems like you want to make a network application/server, and for these performance might be of very great importance - but most probably I'm just being paranoid and this will not be your application's bottleneck. Stability is much more of concern, and, unless you experience real troubles with performance, it is considered to be much better practice to enable as much stability&safety&portability as possible. `Enum.IsDefined` is much more understandable, portable and stable than the explicit boundaries checking.)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the replies. As confirmed by all of you, there is indeed no way to do this out-of-the-box. For the benefit of others I thought I'd post the (custom) code I ended up writing. I wrote an extension method that utilizes a custom attribute on the enum value that I called `[CatchAll]`.

```
public class CatchAll : Attribute { }
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static T ToEnum<T, U>(this U value) where T : struct, IConvertible where U : struct, IComparable, IConvertible, IFormattable, IComparable<U>, IEquatable<U>
    {
        var result = (T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), value);
        var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().ToList();

        if (!values.Contains(result))
        {
            foreach (var enumVal in from enumVal in values
                                    let info = typeof(T).GetField(enumVal.ToString())
                                    let attrs = info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CatchAll), false)
                                    where attrs.Length == 1
                                    select enumVal)
            {
                result = enumVal;
                break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

So then I just have to apply that `[CatchAll]` attribute to the Other value in the enum definition. Then I can do things like this:

```
int value = 13;
var result = value.ToEnum<NetConnectionStatus, int>();
Assert.AreEqual(NetConnectionStatus.Other, result);
```

And this:

```
ushort value = 20;
result = value.ToEnum<NetConnectionStatus, ushort>();
Assert.AreEqual(NetConnectionStatus.Other, result);
```